# Faster and more efficient python method for fuzzy matching substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, difflib

I want the program to search for all occurrences of crocodile, etc with fuzzy matching i.e. If there are any spelling mistakes, it should count those words as well.

```
s="Difference between a crocodile and an alligator is......." #Long paragraph, >10000 words
to_search=["crocodile","insect","alligator"]

for i in range(len(to_search)):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        a = s[j:j+len(to_search[i])]
        match = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,a,to_search[I]).ratio()
        if(match>0.9): #90% similarity
            print(a)
```

So all of the following should be considered as instances of "crocodile": "crocodile","crocodil","crocodele",etc

The above method works but is too slow if the main string ("s" here) is of large size like >1million words. 
Is there any way to do this that's **faster** than the above method**?

**(splitting the string into sub-string sized blocks and then comparing sub-string with reference word)

Comment: SOUNDEX and similar things should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons it takes too long on a large body of text is that you are repeating the sliding window through the entire text multiple times, once for each words you are searching for. And a lot of the computation is on comparing your words to blocks of the same length which might contain parts of multiple words.

If you are willing to posit that you are always looking to match individual words, you could split the text into words and just compare against the words - far fewer comparisons (number of words, vs. windows starting at every position in the text), and the splitting only needs to be done once, not for every search term. Here's an example:

```
to_search= ["crocodile", "insect", "alligator"]
s = "Difference between a crocodile and an alligator is" #Long paragraph, >10000 words
s_words = s.replace(".", " ").split(" ") # Split on spaces, with periods removed
for search_for in to_search:
    for s_word in s_words:
        match = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, s_word, search_for).ratio()
        if(match > 0.9):  #90% similarity
            print(s_word)
            continue      # no longer need to continue the search for this word!
```

This should give you significant speedup, hope it solves your needs!

Happy Coding!

Comment: I would also argue that it would also be a good idea to put the longer loop (words in document) outside the shorter one (search terms). This improves memory locality of your operations. By this I mean, if the list of words is too big for physical memory, putting the longer loop inside the shorter, may require each chunk of the longer list to be swapped into memory multiple times.

Comment: @AmitaiIrron a reasonable point, though then it becomes harder to know when you can stop searching, and would require adding tracking of which words have been found. Tradeoffs!